# Application crash on some android devices when I took a photo

Tags: android, camera, nativescript, nativescript-google-maps-sdk

The application periodically crashes after I take photos. This happens most often on Xiaomi (redmi 3s, redmi 4x) and Nokia (6.1) phones. When you return from the camera, the application restarts itself and writes the following errors in the device’s console:

ActivityManager: Process org.nativescript.TestCameraApp (pid 8370) has died: prev LA
or
ActivityManager: Process ua.com.getmancar (pid 615) has died: prev S

I also want to note that such a problem does not always appear, it happens after the first photo, it happens after 7, and sometimes after 20.
As a test method, I noticed that these errors appear if you use the plugin "nativescript-google-maps-sdk

Comment: It sounds like your memory runs out while processing photo. Did you add `android:largeHeap="true"` to your application tag? If it still crashes after adding, please share complete error log from device monitor.

Comment: You use camera intent to get the photos, don't you?

Comment: Yes, I use the camera to take photos.

Comment: Your solution helped on some devices, but for example on Xiaomi redmi 3s this did not work. This phone unfortunately doesn’t give any notifications to the device’s console and sidekick console, it just restarts the application.